# Provision Grant - Events (Java)

Tags: java, box-api, boxapiv2

Given many users using Provision Grants, how do I determine from the event stream which event corresponds to which grant?

If any file changes underneath the root folder of the Provision Grant I want to respond to that change, but I need to be able to determine which one it is from. I understand I get the folder ID back, but will the events indicate which folder its "under" (even nested 2+ deep)?

Comment: I have a even more basic problem in that I can't get events across all the provisioned users, as I can't even authenticate at the "app level".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible and provision grants aren't appropriate for this task.